# Griffon checkbox binding won't work

Tags: checkbox, griffon

i am trying the following griffon code

on model:

@Bindable boolean hello1=false

on view:

checkBox(id:1,text: 'hello1', constraints:'wrap',selected:bind(target: model, targetProperty:'hello1'))

but it does say

ERROR org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder - An error occurred while building test.TestView@1132e76
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Object.setVariable() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.Collections$EmptyMap, java.util.Arrays$ArrayList) values: [[:], [1, javax.swing.JCheckBox[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@b101cf,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=false,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=]]]8-mar-2012 12.03.41 groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport createNode
AVVERTENZA: Could not find match for name 'setVariable'

i dont get what's the deal, i copied that from working examples on internet....

Comment: If @aalmiray's solution worked, please mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a String instead of a number for the value of the id: property, like this

checkBox(id: 'c1', ...)